# How to include two nested associated siblings in json - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this structure

```
user
   -> profile
       -> address (table)
       -> workplace (table)
```

and i have this code that does not work as expected, it does not output the address nested association

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users.as_json(include: 
                                  [:profile => { 
                                    :include => :address,:include =>:workplace 
                                    }
                                  ]
                                )

  end
```

Comment: make sure that you specify the associations on your questions next time.  Saying `structure` is vague.

Comment: title said nested associations, thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to make it work here is the answer for future reference

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users.as_json(include:
                                  [:profile => {
                                    :include => [:address,:workplace]
                                    }
                                  ]
                                )

  end
```